# Error when launching salt-master

Tags: python, saltstack

I have this error when I execute `salt-master`:

```
# salt-master 
[ERROR   ] Failed to read the virtual function for module: apt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/loader.py", line 861, in gen_functions
    virtual
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/utils/__init__.py", line 1652, in warn_until
    salt_version=_version_.formatted_version
RuntimeError: The warning triggered on filename '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/loader.py', line number 861, is supposed to be shown until version 2014.1.0 (Hydrogen) is released. Current version is now 2014.1.13 (Hydrogen). Please remove the warning.
[ERROR   ] Failed to read the virtual function for module: apt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/loader.py", line 861, in gen_functions
    virtual
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/utils/__init__.py", line 1652, in warn_until
    salt_version=_version_.formatted_version
RuntimeError: The warning triggered on filename '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/loader.py', line number 861, is supposed to be shown until version 2014.1.0 (Hydrogen) is released. Current version is now 2014.1.13 (Hydrogen). Please remove the warning.
[ERROR   ] Failed to read the virtual function for module: apt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/loader.py", line 861, in gen_functions
    virtual
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/utils/__init__.py", line 1652, in warn_until
    salt_version=_version_.formatted_version
RuntimeError: The warning triggered on filename '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/loader.py', line number 861, is supposed to be shown until version 2014.1.0 (Hydrogen) is released. Current version is now 2014.1.13 (Hydrogen). Please remove the warning.
[ERROR   ] Failed to read the virtual function for module: apt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/loader.py", line 861, in gen_functions
    virtual
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/utils/__init__.py", line 1652, in warn_until
    salt_version=_version_.formatted_version
RuntimeError: The warning triggered on filename '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/loader.py', line number 861, is supposed to be shown until version 2014.1.0 (Hydrogen) is released. Current version is now 2014.1.13 (Hydrogen). Please remove the warning.
[ERROR   ] Failed to read the virtual function for module: apt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/loader.py", line 861, in gen_functions
    virtual
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/utils/__init__.py", line 1652, in warn_until
    salt_version=_version_.formatted_version
RuntimeError: The warning triggered on filename '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/loader.py', line number 861, is supposed to be shown until version 2014.1.0 (Hydrogen) is released. Current version is now 2014.1.13 (Hydrogen). Please remove the warning.
[ERROR   ] Failed to read the virtual function for module: apt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/loader.py", line 861, in gen_functions
    virtual
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/utils/__init__.py", line 1652, in warn_until
    salt_version=_version_.formatted_version
RuntimeError: The warning triggered on filename '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/loader.py', line number 861, is supposed to be shown until version 2014.1.0 (Hydrogen) is released. Current version is now 2014.1.13 (Hydrogen). Please remove the warning.
^C[WARNING ] Stopping the Salt Master
Process MWorker-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/master.py", line 840, in run
    self.crypticle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/master.py", line 1788, in __init__
    rend=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/minion.py", line 328, in __init__
    self.gen_modules()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/minion.py", line 336, in gen_modules
    whitelist=self.whitelist)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/loader.py", line 116, in minion_mods
    provider_overrides=True
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/loader.py", line 937, in gen_functions
    'Added {0} to {1}'.format(module_func_name, self.tag)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/log/mixins.py", line 26, in trace
Process MWorker-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/master.py", line 841, in run
    self.aes_funcs = AESFuncs(self.opts, self.crypticle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/master.py", line 865, in __init__
    rend=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/minion.py", line 322, in __init__
    self.opts['grains'] = salt.loader.grains(opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/loader.py", line 321, in grains
    grains_info = load.gen_grains()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/loader.py", line 1034, in gen_grains
    ret = fun()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/grains/core.py", line 1094, in ip6
    return {'ipv6': salt.utils.network.ip_addrs6(include_loopback=True)}
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/utils/network.py", line 552, in ip_addrs6
    ifaces = interfaces()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/utils/network.py", line 426, in interfaces
    return linux_interfaces()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/utils/network.py", line 312, in linux_interfaces
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT).communicate()[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 791, in communicate
    self.log(getattr(logging, 'TRACE', 5), msg, *args, **kwargs)
    stdout = _eintr_retry_call(self.stdout.read)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 476, in _eintr_retry_call
    return func(*args)
KeyboardInterrupt
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1216, in log
Process MWorker-6:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
Process MWorker-8:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/master.py", line 841, in run
    self.aes_funcs = AESFuncs(self.opts, self.crypticle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/master.py", line 865, in __init__
    rend=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/minion.py", line 322, in __init__
    self.opts['grains'] = salt.loader.grains(opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/loader.py", line 301, in grains
    salt.config.DEFAULT_MINION_OPTS['conf_file']
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/config.py", line 590, in load_config
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/master.py", line 841, in run
Process MWorker-7:
    opts = _read_conf_file(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/config.py", line 517, in _read_conf_file
    conf_opts = yaml.safe_load(conf_file.read()) or {}
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 93, in safe_load
Traceback (most recent call last):
    self.aes_funcs = AESFuncs(self.opts, self.crypticle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/master.py", line 865, in __init__
    rend=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/minion.py", line 322, in __init__
    self.opts['grains'] = salt.loader.grains(opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/loader.py", line 301, in grains
    salt.config.DEFAULT_MINION_OPTS['conf_file']
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/config.py", line 590, in load_config
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
    opts = _read_conf_file(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/config.py", line 517, in _read_conf_file
    conf_opts = yaml.safe_load(conf_file.read()) or {}
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 93, in safe_load
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/master.py", line 841, in run
    self.aes_funcs = AESFuncs(self.opts, self.crypticle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/master.py", line 865, in __init__
    rend=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/minion.py", line 322, in __init__
    self.opts['grains'] = salt.loader.grains(opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/loader.py", line 321, in grains
    grains_info = load.gen_grains()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/loader.py", line 1029, in gen_grains
    funcs = self.gen_functions()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/loader.py", line 707, in gen_functions
    ), fn_, path, desc
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/grains/core.py", line 15, in <module>
    import socket
KeyboardInterrupt
    return load(stream, SafeLoader)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 71, in load
    return loader.get_single_data()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 37, in get_single_data
    return load(stream, SafeLoader)
    self._log(level, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1270, in _log
    record = self.makeRecord(self.name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func, extra)
KeyboardInterrupt
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 71, in load
    return loader.get_single_data()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 37, in get_single_data
    node = self.get_single_node()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 36, in get_single_node
    node = self.get_single_node()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 35, in get_single_node
    if not self.check_event(StreamEndEvent):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 98, in check_event
    document = self.compose_document()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 55, in compose_document
    node = self.compose_node(None, None)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 133, in compose_mapping_node
    item_value = self.compose_node(node, item_key)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 133, in compose_mapping_node
    item_value = self.compose_node(node, item_key)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 82, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_sequence_node(anchor)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 110, in compose_sequence_node
    while not self.check_event(SequenceEndEvent):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 98, in check_event
    self.current_event = self.state()
    self.current_event = self.state()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 143, in parse_implicit_document_start
    StreamEndToken):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 116, in check_token
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 382, in parse_block_sequence_entry
    if self.check_token(BlockEntryToken):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 116, in check_token
    self.fetch_more_tokens()
    self.fetch_more_tokens()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 156, in fetch_more_tokens
    self.scan_to_next_token()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 781, in scan_to_next_token
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 156, in fetch_more_tokens
    self.forward()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/reader.py", line 99, in forward
    self.scan_to_next_token()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 780, in scan_to_next_token
    while self.peek() not in u'\0\r\n\x85\u2028\u2029':
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/reader.py", line 88, in peek
    def forward(self, length=1):
KeyboardInterrupt
    try:
KeyboardInterrupt
```

My salt-version is:

```
           Salt: 2014.1.13
         Python: 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56)
         Jinja2: 2.7.2
       M2Crypto: 0.21.1
 msgpack-python: 0.3.0
   msgpack-pure: Not Installed
       pycrypto: 2.6.1
         PyYAML: 3.10
          PyZMQ: 14.1.1
            ZMQ: 4.0.4
```

I followed the official documentation (Ubuntu Installation) and I am using Linux Mint for local tests. Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: How goes the battle?

Comment: I don't remember how I solve it, but I think I made an upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use bootstrap.sh to install? I would recommend re-running it.

On my Ubuntu server the following packages are dependencies of salt-{master,common,minion} version 2014.1.13:

```
dctrl-tools     python-crypto       python-pkg-resources    python-yaml
msgpack-python  python-jinja2       python-requests         python-zmq
python-m2crypto python-support
```

Make sure to apt-get all of them.